# Execute command with windows command line and capture output in rolling file

Tags: windows, logging, command-line

I have a command line program that produces output that I would like to log to a file.

I know that I can redirect the output of a command (foo.exe for example) to a file using the > operator, but for this current project I need more than just simple output functionality. I would also mention that I can't change any of the code in foo.exe.

I am looking for a command line utility/command that can do the following:

1. Log the output of a foo.exe to a file
2. Place a timestamp on each individual output of foo.exe
3. When the current log file reaches a certain specified size (say 1mb), close the current file and start putting log data in a new file.

In a perfect world the utility would encapsulate the command I wish to execute and log its output, looking something like the following:

log.exe -MaxLogSize=1mb -FileName="FooOutput.log" -Execute="foo.exe"

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Check if rotatelogs from Apache does what you need

Comment: It doesn't appear to do what I need. I don't think I can (or am not sure how I would) configure foo.exe to output to the stdin of rotatelogs. See ( http://serverfault.com/questions/419792/rotate-other-logs-with-rotatelogs-exe)

Comment: Foo | rotatelogs ?!?

Comment: Sorry, I had seen the serverfault question earlier and took it to mean that some sort of configuration needed to be done inside foo.exe. That works but I don't see any sort of option to append a timestamp to each output of foo.exe, is there an option in rotatelogs or perhaps another program I could pipe this through to get a timestamp? Something like ts in [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what rotatelogs does when used with Apache

Comment: Yes, but when I look here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html I don't see any parameters that would allow for rotatelogs to append a timestamp to each line of output piped into its stdin, and when I run this with my application it doesn't include any timestamps by default, so is it possible that Apache is adding the timestamps?

Comment: Rotatelogs can only add a timestamp to the filename. To add it per line you will have to pipe from foo to something new and then rotatelogs

Comment: Yeah, I was asking if you perhaps knew of a utility in windows to do this with. There is a moreutils library for unix that has a utility called ts. When you pipe output through ts, it appends a timestamp to each line it gets from stdin. Regardless, thanks for your help!

Comment: No moreutils port for Windows? There is cygwin, perhaps you can get moreutils / TS that way

Comment: Yeah, I can't install cygwin, otherwise I wouldn't be going down this path at all. Thanks though!